# Filling out and Saving a PDF on android

Tags: java, android, pdf

so basically what I am attempting to do, is to create a PDF that information can be inputted by the user of that document. and when all the information is entered, be able to click the save button below on the PDF document, and a window prompt open allowing the user to "save as" the document to a certain directory.

I currently have the button working for Windows OS, and the prompt comes up to save as, however when opened on Adobe reader on an android phone and the save button is clicked, nothing happens.. is there a java script code that differs from the Windows version to what android would look like.

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider Xamarin for android app development then you could take a look at the following [blog post](http://blog.apitron.com/2015/01/manipulate-pdf-on-ios-and-android-using-apitron-pdf-kit-and-xamarin.html) showing how to create PDF file with arbitrary content on Android and iOS using the same library.